# Plot a curved trajectory on a 2D coordinate system

Tags: c++, math, 2d, curve

I have a few ordered points (less than 10) in 2D coordinates system.
I have an agent moving in the system and **I want to find the shortest path between those points following their order**.
For background the agent can be given a position to go to with a thrust, and my objective is to plot the fastest course given the fact that the agent has a maximum thrust and maximum angular velocity.
After some research I realized that I may be looking for a curve fitting algorithm, but I don't know the underlying function since the points are randomly distributed in the coordinates system.
Please, help me find a solution to this problem.
I am open to any suggestion, my prefered programming language being C++.

Comment: Google is your friend: C++/Boost has polynomial fitting libraries that you can use.  The randomness of the points is immaterial when it comes to fitting.  Your constraints about minimum time, maximum thrust and angular velocity are more difficult issues.  I'd suggest that you break your problem into pieces and solve it that way.  Relax some of your constraints, get a solution, then add constraints back.  When I hear "miniumum time" I think of Dijkstra's algorithm through a graph.  Maybe you need to evaluate all possible graphs and pick the minimum one.

Comment: @duffymo thanks, could you elaborate on polynomial fitting in Boost ? I am honestly lost when it comes to fitting ; my programmer friends have talked about Djikstra too, but I am not sure how to relate this algorithm to my problem

Comment: @JensHöpken the problem is : my agent must follow a determined order between the points

Comment: Then it's even easier: You know the path.  There are fewer to check.  Your wording is incorrect: you don't want shortest path, you want minimum time to traverse the known path.    Every NASCAR racer knows that "bang-bang" control gets you there fastest: full on the accelerator, full on the brake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a pure mathematical solution such as [spacecraft trajectory optimization for example](http://prussing.ae.illinois.edu/AE508/P_2.pdf), but here is how I would consider approaching it from a programming/annealing perspective.

Even though you need a continuous path, you might start the path search with discreet steps and a tolerance for getting close enough to each point as a start.

- Assign a certain amount of time to each step and vary applied angular force and thrust at each step.
- Calculate resulting angular momentum and position for the start of the next step.
- Select the parameters for the next step either with a random search, or iterate through each to find the closest to the next target point (quantize the selection of angles and thrust to begin with). Repeat steps until you are close enough to the next target point. Then repeat to get to the next point.

Once you have a rough path you can start refining it (perhaps use the rough point from the previous run as target points in the new one) by reducing the time/size of the steps and tolerance to target points.

When evaluating the parameters' fitness at each step you might want to consider that once you reach a target point you also want to perhaps have momentum in the direction of the next point. This should be an emergent property if multiple paths are considered and the fitness function considers shortest total time.

c++ could help here if you use the std::priority_queue and std::map for example to keep track of the potential paths.